# How does offset rows fetch next works

Tags: sql-server, offset

I have following select statement inside a stored procedure:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.vehicle
ORDER BY date
OFFSET ((@num_pages - 1) * @nb_elements) ROWS FETCH NEXT (@nb_elements) ROWS ONLY
```

where `@num_pages` and `@nb_elements` are my stored procedure entry parameters.

Will the `SELECT * FROM dbo.vehicle` be fully computed and then only my `@nb_elements` will returned? Or does the `SELECT * FROM dbo.vehicle` statement will be stopped when hits the `@nb_elements` row?

I have huge performance issues on a stored procedure which uses this kind of statement.

Comment: have you taken a look at the query plan?

Comment: The result is not fully computed but performance will become progressively worse during pagination depending on the specified OFFSET because the preceding rows must be scanned. Make sure the ORDER BY column(s) is indexed. If you still have performance issues, post you actual query with DDL for the table, including indexes. Your example is not valid T-SQL.

Comment: You can see the effect quite easily by using `set statistics io on` and then running your procedure with different values. You'll get the number of logical reads printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a huge performance problem with that type of statement because that is not a valid statement. `OFFSET` is only valid as part of an `ORDER BY`.

It sorts, moves down an `OFFSET` number of rows, and then return the `ROWS FETCH NEXT`.  Moving down `OFFSET` number of rows is not what is killing your performance.

[order by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: I forgot the     ORDER BY. By the way this is just an example. So if I get it well, if I have 100 rows in my table, the select will get the 100 rows, ordered on my date, and then apply the     FETCH ?

Comment: What it does is in the link in my question.